# Add Row in Listview Itemtemplate after each date records

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a listview which is bind to a datatable. Datatable have records between two given dates.
I want to calculate day total date wise as show in picture , But day total Row displayafter each record.. I want to show day total of each date group.
[image]

Here is my code..

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvRR" OnItemDataBound="lvRR_DataBound"  OnItemCommand="lvRR_ItemCommand" runat="server"  ItemPlaceholderID="plchldr" >
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table id='tblViewDate' class='tblViewDate' align=center border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% >                          
                                <tr   class='GridviewScrollHeader'>                                  
                                    <th scope="col"    style='min-width:150px !important;font-weight:bold' width="5%" align="left" valign="middle">
                                       &nbsp;ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th  scope="col"  style='min-width:350px !important;font-weight:bold' align="left" valign="middle" >
                                        &nbsp;From
                                    </th>                                   
                                  <th scope="col"     style='min-width:200px !important;font-weight:bold' align="left" valign="middle">
                                      To
                                    </th>                                 
                                    <th scope="col"    style='min-width:100px !important;font-weight:bold' align="left" valign="middle">
                                        &nbsp;Total Return Quantity 
                                    </th>                                    
                                    <th scope="col"    style='min-width:100px !important;font-weight:bold' align="left" valign="middle">
                                        &nbsp;Total Rejection Quantity <br />(In no. of Bottles)
                                    </th>                                 
                                </tr>

                                 <tr id="plchldr" runat="server" />

                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel  runat="server" ID="pnlDate" Visible=true>
                            <tr id="Tr1"  class='GridviewScrollItem GridviewScrollItem1' runat="server" ><%--visible='<%# Container.DataItemIndex.ToString()== "0" ? true : false %>'--%>
                                <td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;height:20px;font-size:12px;border-right:1px solid #686868 !important;'  >&nbsp;
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("RejectDate")).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>'></asp:Label>  </td>
                                <td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;height:20px;font-size:12px;border-right:1px solid #686868 !important;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:12px;border-right:1px solid #686868 !important;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:12px;border-right:1px solid #686868 !important;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:12px;border-right:1px solid #686868 !important;'>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </asp:Panel>
                            <tr  class='GridviewScrollItem'>                              
                                <td align="left" valign="middle"  >
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRRAutoID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RRAutoID")%>' /> 
                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" />                         
                                   <asp:Label ID="lnkRejectID"   ToolTip="Click here to see details!" style="color:#2AA5BC;cursor:pointer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Options").ToString()=="return" ? Eval("ReturnID") : Eval("RejectID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle"  >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFrom"   runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReturnFrom") %>'   ></asp:Label>
                                </td>

                              <td align="left" valign="middle" class="browsehhh555">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTo" CssClass="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReturnTo") %>' />
                                </td>
                              <td align="left" valign="middle" >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalRejectQuantity" CssClass="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalReturnQuantity").ToString().Replace(".00","") %>' />
                                </td>
                              <td align="left" valign="middle" >
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalRejectQuantity").ToString().Replace(".00","") %>' />
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                              <asp:Panel  runat="server" ID="pnlDayTotal" Visible=true>
                              <tr>
                                    <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #AAAAAA">&nbsp;</td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #AAAAAA">&nbsp;</td><td class='tdShift' style='text-align:right !important;height:20px !important;cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;;white-space:nowrap;'>Day Total&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class='clsTotal' style='font-weight:normal;height:20px;text-align:right;width:100px !important;white-space:nowrap;'><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrDayTotalReturn" Text="@"></asp:Literal></td>
                                    <td class='clsTotal' style='font-weight:normal;height:20px;text-align:right;width:100px !important;white-space:nowrap;'><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrDayTotalRejection" Text="#"></asp:Literal></td>
                              </tr>
                              </asp:Panel>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

Cs Part is ...

```
 public string temDate = ""; public string temDayTotal = ""; public string temDTDate = ""; 
protected void lvRR_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblFrom = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblFrom");
        Label lblTo = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTo");
        Panel pnlDate = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlDate");
        Panel pnlDayTotal = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlDayTotal");
        Label lblDate = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate");
        if (pnlDate != null)
        {
            temDTDate = lblDate.Text.ToString();
            if (lblDate.Text.ToString() == temDate)
            {
                pnlDate.Visible = false; //pnlDayTotal.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pnlDate.Visible = true; //pnlDayTotal.Visible = true;
            }
            temDate = lblDate.Text.ToString();

            if (temDTDate != temDate)
            {
               pnlDayTotal.Visible = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Add Following code after bind listview ..

```
 decimal sTotalReturn =0;     decimal sTotalReject =0;
            for (Int32 ii = 0; ii < lvRR.Items.Count;ii++ )
            {

                Label lblTotalReturnQuantity = ((Label)lvRR.Items[ii].FindControl("lblTotalReturnQuantity"));
                Label lblTotalRejectQuantity = ((Label)lvRR.Items[ii].FindControl("lblTotalRejectQuantity"));
                Label lblDate = ((Label)lvRR.Items[ii] .FindControl("lblDate"));
                Panel pnlDayTotal = ((Panel)lvRR.Items[ii].FindControl("pnlDayTotal"));


                Literal ltrDayTotalReturn = ((Literal)lvRR.Items[ii].FindControl("ltrDayTotalReturn"));
                Literal ltrDayTotalRejection = ((Literal)lvRR.Items[ii].FindControl("ltrDayTotalRejection"));

                sTotalReturn = sTotalReturn + Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalReturnQuantity.Text);
                sTotalReject = sTotalReject + Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalRejectQuantity.Text);

                if (ii + 1 < lvRR.Items.Count)
                {
                    Label lblDateNext = ((Label)lvRR.Items[ii + 1].FindControl("lblDate"));

                    if (lblDate.Text.ToString().Trim() != lblDateNext.Text.ToString().Trim())
                    {
                        pnlDayTotal.Visible = true;
                        ltrDayTotalReturn.Text = sTotalReturn.ToString();
                        ltrDayTotalRejection.Text = sTotalReject.ToString(); sTotalReturn = 0; sTotalReject = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    pnlDayTotal.Visible = true;
                    ltrDayTotalReturn.Text = sTotalReturn.ToString();
                    ltrDayTotalRejection.Text = sTotalReject.ToString();
                    sTotalReturn = 0; sTotalReject = 0;
                }


            }
```